# wget downloads image in terminal but not Geektool

Tags: image, download, wget, geektool

I am using Geektool to download an image from the internet and then display it on the desktop. The wget code downloads it fine when using Terminal but it doesn't work when using Geektools.

```
wget -O status_logo.png "$WEBSITEURL"
```

I was hoping that someone would have some experience with Geektools and downloading photos.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X doesn't have wget by default, so I suspect yours is installed in a directory that is not in a $PATH loaded by GeekTool.

Try putting the full path to wget or use curl instead.

Comment: I just saw you comment as I haven't signed in awhile. I did set my path as you suggested and it worked. export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"